# c++ class destructor deleting some but not all member data

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-arrays

I've read through different resources but feel like I'm missing something. I'm explicitly calling the destructor when a variable (numItems) reaches zero. I have a loop that prints all the class objects (students), but while any object that had the destructor called on it has a blank first and last name, the ID and numItems variables still exist. Am I misunderstanding how the destructor works? Why would it delete some but not all of the member attributes?

Also, the "items" are stored in a dynamic array. I can set and access them as long as the array is public. But even using setters, the program crashes if I attempt to populate a private array.

Header:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define ARRAY_MAX 15
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    string firstName, lastName;
    unsigned int ID, numItems = 0;
    typedef string* StringPtr;
    //StringPtr items;


public:
    int capacity = 15;
    string *items = new string[capacity];
    Student();
    Student(const unsigned int id, const string fName, const string lName);
    string getfName() const;
    string getlName() const;
    unsigned int getnumItems() const;
    string getItem(int num);
    unsigned int getID() const;
    void setfName(string fname);
    void setlName(string lname);
    void setID(unsigned int id);
    void setItem(string str, int num);
    int CheckoutCount();
    bool CheckOut(const string& item);
    bool CheckIn(const string& item);
    bool HasCheckedOut(const string& item);
    void Clear();
    ~Student();
    //const Student operator+(string rhs);
    //void operator+=(string rhs);
    //bool operator==(Student rhs);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Student& stu);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Student& stu);

};
#endif // STUDENT_H
```

Definitions:

```
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

Student::Student()
{
}

Student::Student(const unsigned int id, const string fName, const string lName)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    ID = id;
}

string Student::getfName() const
{
    return firstName;
}

string Student::getlName() const
{
    return lastName;
}

unsigned int Student::getnumItems() const
{
    return numItems;
}

string Student::getItem(int num)
{

    return items[num];
}

unsigned int Student::getID() const
{
    return ID;
}

void Student::setfName(string fname)
{
    firstName = fname;
}

void Student::setlName(string lname)
{
    lastName = lname;
}

void Student::setID(unsigned int id)
{
    if ((id >= 1000) && (id <= 100000))
    {
        ID = id;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Attempted ID for " << firstName << " " << lastName << " is invalid. Must be between 1000 and 100,000." << endl;
    }
}

void Student::setItem(string str, int num)
{
    items[num] = str;
}

int Student::CheckoutCount()
{
    return numItems;
}

bool Student::CheckOut(const string & item)
{
    if (this->HasCheckedOut(item) == true)
    {
        return false; // already found item in list, CheckOut failed...
    }
    else
    {
        items[numItems] = item;
        numItems++;
        return true; // CheckOut successful
    }

}

bool Student::CheckIn(const string & item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] == item)
        {
            for (; i < numItems - 1; i++)
            {
                // Assign the next element to current location.             
                items[i] = items[i + 1];
            }

            // Remove the last element as it has been moved to previous index.
            items[numItems - 1] = "";
            numItems = numItems - 1;
            if (numItems == 0)
            {
                this->~Student();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

bool Student::HasCheckedOut(const string & item)
{
    string *end = items + numItems;
    string *result = find(items, end, item);
    if (result != end)
    {
        return true; // found value at "result" pointer location...
    }
    else
        return false;
}

void Student::Clear()
{
    ID = 0;
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    delete[] items;
}

Student::~Student()
{
}

istream & operator>>(istream & input, Student & stu)
{
    string temp;
    input >> stu.ID >> stu.firstName >> stu.lastName >> stu.numItems;
    int loopnum = stu.numItems;
    if (loopnum > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < loopnum; i++)
        {
            input >> temp;
            stu.setItem(temp, i);
        }
    }
    return input;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, const Student & stu)
{
    string s = stu.firstName + " " + stu.lastName;
    output << setw(8) << stu.ID << setw(16) << s << setw(8) << stu.numItems;
    int loopnum = stu.numItems;
    if (loopnum > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < loopnum; i++)
        {
            output << stu.items[i] << "  ";
        }
    }
    output << endl << endl;
    return output;
}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;

void fcheck(ifstream &mystream);

int main()
{
    ifstream sin("students.txt");           // File input/output variables
    ifstream fin("checkins.txt");
    ifstream chin("checkouts.txt");
    ofstream sout("UpdatedStudentsC.txt");
    Student stu1, stu2;

    fcheck(sin);
    fcheck(fin);
    fcheck(chin);

    typedef Student* StuPtr;
    StuPtr studentList;
    int stud_capacity = 50;
    studentList = new Student[stud_capacity];
    int num_studs = 0;


    sout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left); // justify output to format properly.
    while (sin.good())              // While there's data in the file, do stuff.
    {
        sin >> stu1;

        stu1.CheckIn("Towel");
        stu1.CheckIn("Locker");
        if (stu1.getnumItems() == 0)
        {
            stu1.~Student();
        }
        studentList[num_studs] = stu1;
        num_studs++;

        sout << stu1; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        cout << studentList[i].getID() << " " << studentList[i].getfName() << "  " << studentList[i].getnumItems() <<  endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    // Close files
    fin.close();
    chin.close();
    sout.close();
    sin.close();

    // Quit without error
    return 0;
}

void fcheck(ifstream &mystream)
{
    if (!mystream)                          // If we can't find the input file, quit with error message.
    {
        cout << "file not opened!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So much code! And `typedef string* StringPtr;` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `stu1.~Student();`? There are very few cases in which you should be manually calling a destructor and I highly doubt this is one of them

Comment: Just a few comments: 1) use smart pointers and containers, *not* raw `new`/`delete`. 2) "`#define ARRAY_MAX 15`" - No. Use a `const int`. 3) "`using namespace std;`" - generally a bad idea. 4) Your destructor does nothing. Either fix it to actually do its job (of deleting what you allocated) or see point 1 and then `=default` it. 5) "`if (result != end)
    {
        return true; .`" - just `return result != end;`. 6) embrace range-based for loops.   And more...

Comment: I guess I mistakenly believed that it would remove the dynamic array and all the class attributes. Basically "undo" the work that was done when the object was created. Why would it delete the string variables but not the int ID?

Comment: And when I placed explicit instructions in the destructor like " delete [] items;" it always crashed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  It's even worse to do it in headers, as that inflicts it on everyone who uses that header.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: I don't have the reputation yet to upvote comments, but wanted to mention the advice on improving my posts and overall code was also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A destructor deletes nothing if you don't tell it to (just like now, your destructor is empty). A destructor is meant to perform some cleanup before the object is deallocated, but it does not deallocate.

Destructors are implicitly invoked

- when a stack object goes out of scope,
- when a heap object is deallocated with `delete`.

Comment: So assuming I want to delete the object, is the correct procedure to call the destructor on the class object for "cleanup", and then delete the object?

Comment: @JustinScott: reread my answer.

Comment: @JustinScott You *never* directly call the destructor. Ok, that's not quite true. there are times when you must, notably using a technique like *placement-new*, which you're *not* doing. Instead, the destructor is called *for you* in the manner Yves describes in the above answer.

Comment: If you want to delete the object, then `delete` it (if you created it with `new`), or leave its scope (if it's of automatic duration).

Answer (score 0):

> while any object that had the destructor called on it has a blank first and last name, the ID and numItems variables still exist.

None of the member variables of the destroyed object exist anymore.

There is no way to inspect in C++ whether an object has been destroyed or not. When you try to access the members of the destroyed object, the program will have undefined behaviour. One possible behaviour might be something that you might expect from a destroyed object, and another possible behaviour might be something that you didn't expect.

---

You call the destructor of a local automatic variable `stu1`, but you don't construct a new object in place. When the variable goes out of scope, it is destroyed "again". This also causes the program to have undefined behaviour. Needing to call a destructor explicitly is very rare case, and this is not such case.